# Highlight parent Menu if part of url matchs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight parent menu whenever part of url matchs the main url

Main navigation as below

```
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li> <a href="/en/" data-subnav="home-subnav" class="mm-nav-item"> HOME  </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/en/latest/" data-subnav="newissue-subnav" class="mm-nav-item"> LASTEST UPDATES  </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/en/categories/" data-subnav="categories-subnav" class="mm-nav-item"> CATEGORIES  </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/en/news/" data-subnav="news-subnav" class="mm-nav-item"> NEWS  </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/en/contact-us/" data-subnav="contact-subnav" class="mm-nav-item"> CONTACT US  </a> </li>
</ul>
```

and some pages have subpages such as news page has news details page and url for

> new page = /en/news/
>
> new details page = /en/news/xxx/title-of-the-news-what-ever-it-is

so i want to highlight the parent menu `News` wheneven one is on news details page

```
 $(".main-nav li a").each(function () {
        //this part works when url matches
        if (this.href == window.location.href) {
            $(this).addClass("active-link");
        }

        //this part u want to match when part of url matchs
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('/news/') > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("active-link");
        }
    });
```

Below part of code highligts from all menus while i want `news` menu to be highlighted when ever user is on new detail page

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/news/') > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("active-link");
        }
```

Comment: Remove the `.active-link` from the HTML first.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory, I tried that `$(".main-nav li a").removeClass("active-link");` it didnt work

Comment: @Learning He meant to remove the classes from HTML manually.

Comment: @KK, Sorry my mistake as i copy pasted code from html forgot to remove it from question. in actual code there is no `active-link` class, i only add it with javascript as shown in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try modifying the code from:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/news/') > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("active-link");
    }
```

to

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/news/') > -1&&this.href.indexOf("/news/")>-1) {
      $(this).addClass("active-link");
}
```

Comment: @k, I have tried both options it still highlights all menu items, for some reason it match all urls.

Comment: @Learning Check the updated answer. You also need to check the anchor's attribute while iterating. The second if loop is always true whenever user is on "news" links.

Comment: This doesnt highlight anything

Comment: I replace my code with your code, it return false for all menu items

Comment: your code works in fiddle but fails on localhost not sure what is causing issue, It should work, I copy pasted code and replace sample url with `window.location.href` as well as `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(".main-nav li a").each(function (index, element) {
    //this part works when url matches
    if (element.href == window.location.href) {
        $(element).addClass("active-link");
        return false;
    }

    //this part u want to match when part of url matchs
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('/news/') > 0) {
        $(element).addClass("active-link");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This highlights all menu items.

Comment: `element` is nothing but alternate of `this` object.

Comment: try returning false after condition matches, i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want

```
$(".main-nav li a").each(function (e) {
        //this part works when url matches
       var attr = $(this).attr('href').toString();
        console.log(attr)
        //this part u want to match when part of url matchs
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(attr) > -1) {
            $(this).addClass("active-link");
//To highlight parent use $(this).parent('li').addClass("active-link");
        }
    });
```

Comment: there is no child element in menu itself, for this reason i am trying to match it as string `if (window.location.href.indexOf('/news/')`